# How to explain the reentrant RuntimeError caused by printing in signal handlers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, race-condition, reentrancy

Code:

```
# callee.py
import signal
import sys
import time


def int_handler(*args):
    for i in range(10):
        print('INTERRUPT', args)
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, int_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, int_handler)
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

```
# caller.py
import subprocess
import sys


def wait_and_communicate(p):
    out, err = p.communicate(timeout=1)
    print('========out==========')
    print(out.decode() if out else '')
    print('========err==========')
    print(err.decode() if err else '')
    print('=====================')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['/usr/local/bin/python3', 'callee.py'],
        stdout=sys.stdout,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    while 1:
        try:
            wait_and_communicate(p)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            p.terminate()
            wait_and_communicate(p)
            break
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            continue
```

Simply execute `caller.py` and then press `Ctrl+C`, the program will raise `RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'>` randomly. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers) I learn that signal handlers are called asynchronously, and in this case two signals SIGINT(`Ctrl+C` action) and SIGTERM(`p.terminate()`) are sent nearly at the same time, causing a race condition.

However, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699314/how-to-use-a-separate-thread-for-asynchronous-signal-handling-in-python) I learn that `signal` module doesn't execute signal handler inside low-level (C) handler. Instead, **it sets a flag, and the interpreter checks the flag between bytecode instructions and then invokes the python signal handler.** In other words, while signal handlers may mess up the control flow in the main thread, a bytecode instruction is always atomic.

This seems to contradict with the result of my example program. As far as I am concerned, `print` and the implicit `_io.BufferedWriter` are both implemented in pure C, and thus calling `print` function should consume only one bytecode instruction (`CALL_FUNCTION`). I am confused: **within one uninterrupted instruction on one thread, how can a function be reentrant?**

I'm using Python 3.6.2.

Comment: This symptom is weird. I saw the error, but suddenly, I cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 5):

Signals are processed between opscode(see [eval_frame_handle_pending()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1430)
in python's opscode processor loop), but not limited to it. `print` is a perfect example. It is implemented based on [_io_BufferedWriter_write_impl()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c#L1923), which has a structure like

> `ENTER_BUFFERED()`            => it locks buffer
>
> `PyErr_CheckSignals()`        => it invoke signal handler
>
> `LEAVE_BUFFERED()`            => it unlocks buffer

by calling `PyErr_CheckSignals()`, it invoke another signal handler, which has another `print` in this case. The 2nd `print` run `ENTER_BUFFERED()` again, because the buffer is already locked by previous `print` in 1st signal handler, so the `reentrant` exception is thrown as below snippet shows.

```c
    // snippet of ENTER_BUFFERED
    static int
    _enter_buffered_busy(buffered *self)
    {
        int relax_locking;
        PyLockStatus st;
        if (self->owner == PyThread_get_thread_ident()) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                         "reentrant call inside %R", self);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    #define ENTER_BUFFERED(self) \
        ( (PyThread_acquire_lock(self->lock, 0) ? \
           1 : _enter_buffered_busy(self)) \
         && (self->owner = PyThread_get_thread_ident(), 1) )
```

---

P.S.

*Reentrant Functions* from [*Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment*](https://web.archive.org/web/20200130232612/http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/%7Eivana/courses/ps/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch10lev1sec6.html).

The Single UNIX Specification specifies the functions that are guaranteed to be safe to call from within a signal handler. These functions are reentrant and are called async-signal safe. Most of the functions that are not reentrant because

1. they are known to use static data structures,
2. they call malloc or free
3. they are part of the standard I/O library. Most implementations of the standard I/O library use global data structures in a nonreentrant way. `print` in Python belongs to this category.

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer to inhibit delivery of SIGINT to the child, so there's no race,
perhaps by putting it in a different process group,
or by having it ignore the signal.
Then only SIGTERM from the parent would matter.

To reveal where it was interrupted, use this:

```
    sig_num, frame = args
    print(dis.dis(frame.f_code.co_code))
    print(frame.f_lasti)
```

The bytecode offsets in the left margin correspond to
that last instruction executed offset.

Other items of interest include
`frame.f_lineno`,
`frame.f_code.co_filename`, and
`frame.f_code.co_names`.

This issue becomes moot in python 3.7.3, which no longer exhibits the symptom.

Comment: Except I'm seeing it in Python 3.9 in celery while logging